# What software do I use to rotate a video 90 degrees?

Tags: software-recommendation, video-editor

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I rotate a video?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83711/how-can-i-rotate-a-video)

I have some videos that I want to rotate 90 degrees. What software do I use?