# How can I rotate videos across platforms?

Tags: kubuntu, video-editor, quicktime, mov

**Avidemux** was recommended in answer to [question 83711](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83711/how-can-i-rotate-a-video). My question is not quite the same, though it also concerns conversion of video files taken by a "landscape" camera which need to be converted to portrait mode

I have rotated videos (usually .MOV format) in Windows XP, using Apple Quicktime Pro ("QTP"). If done correctly the file remains rotated for other Windows machines without the need to retain the original as a *reference file*, as well as on an iMac, but nevertheless,using Kubuntu 12.04.1,appear in the original unrotated form in Dragon Player ("DP"). DP claims to be no more than a "simple, no frills" player, so I suspect that the problem is that QTP rotates files in a way that is accessible only by QT.

Does Avidemux do better? I need an application, if there is one, which will rotate a moving image so that it stays rotated on any computer!

Comment: There is one way to find out: Try it. I suggest, however, that you use OpenShot, the new(ish) default in Ubuntu. I personally find OpenShot easier than Avidemux.

Comment: If you are comfortable with the command line, try `transpose` video filter in `avconv` from `libav` package. To install it enter `sudo apt-get install libav` and then read the man page `man avconv`.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using kubuntu you may want to try kdenlive (available from official repos), which is a really powerful video editor. It may be somewhat daunting, but it's user-friendly enough to give it a try.

Comment: kdenlive can be used both in Gnome or Unity but when installing, it may bring the required kde components. Even so, there is no need to install KDE to run kdenlive. Tested in 12.04 LTS Precise Pangolin.

Answer (score 0):

I would try OpenShot. It is a video editor which permits, amongst other things video rotation.

To install it, simply type `sudo apt-get install openshot` in a terminal or if you prefer, you may install it through the **Ubuntu Software Center**.

Comment: Thanks Guys, Openshot was available on the Muon Package manager, so I didn't even need the terminal, which still frightens me somewhat. When I've learnt how to drive it, I'll report back - from the help menu it looks hopeful.

Answer (score 0):

kdenlive "Rotate (keyframable)" and "Rotate and shear" Plugins can do what you wish BUT you will be in the need to render a different file which can be made using the same dimensions and codec of the original.

In the next screenshot I am using an iPhone 4S ".mov" video file in order to rotate and crop it in a rectangular 4:3 video project. After which I can run a render to create a new source. The changes will be observed by the majority of the operating systems and their respective video players.

[image]

Good luck!