# How can I rotate video by 180 degrees with avconv

Tags: avconv

I'd like to rotate video (mp4) by 180 degrees, but not flip. Is it possible to do it with avconv?

Comment: I found [with](http://askubuntu.com/a/269459) [both](http://askubuntu.com/a/390818) existing answers that theywork with the MP4 files from a Hero 3 camera, but only after I added `-c:a` copy to the command (just before the output filename). I also found that the second version was indistinguishable quality, but about 50% faster than the chained translate version.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

It is possible using the `transpose` video filter. You cannot rotate by 180 degrees, but you can rotate by 90 degrees and chain the filter.

```
avconv -i video.mp4 -vf transpose=1,transpose=1 out.mkv
```

See `transpose` in the `avconv` manpage:
http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/quantal/en/man1/avconv.1.html

Comment: This rotated my video, but the quality drop (resolution and framerate) was massive (iphone .mov file).

Comment: transpose=clock works now see [my answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/887906/225694)

Answer (score 15):

Yes, but you'll need to add some additional options to your command for it to work properly. Transpose and vflip/hflip should do the trick, but if you don't tell avconv more detail about what you want, you'll likely get very low quality output try:

```
 avconv -i original.mp4 -vf "hflip,vflip" -codec:v libx264 -preset slow -crf 20 -codec:a copy flipped.mp4
```

Notice the `-crf` option. That sets the output quality. It goes from 0 (lossless) upwards logarithmically. You'll probably want a value between 19 and 25 in most cases. `-preset` sets the speed of the encoding, either "slow", "medium", or "fast". Slow should get you smaller file sizes with an obvious tradeoff. You should adjust `-codec:v` to match the original. If you don't set these options you'll get the defaults, which don't work well when flipping iphone video.

Comment: `Unrecognized option 'preset'
Failed to set value 'slow' for option 'preset'`

That's what I got

Comment: ...and without it, I got `Unknown encoder 'libx264'`

Comment: `apt-get install libavcodec-extra-53` solved it

Answer (score 6):

Additional method with avconv is to use vflip and hflip filters. Should run faster and maybe better quality:

```
avconv -i video.mp4 -vf vflip,hflip out.mp4
```

Comment: Same:  This rotated my video, but the quality drop (resolution and framerate) was massive (iphone .mov file).

Comment: @GringoSuave wcarlson has given you a stripped down example, you still need to add all the -codec:v ... and other tags

Answer (score 1):

I did this:

```
avconv -i invertedOne.mp4 -c:a copy -vf "hflip,vflip" rightOne.mp4
```

Full HD video, great results with non perceivable quality loss

Comment: Pure gold for **avconv** version 11.12-6:11.12-1~deb8u9, except that I desired a 90-degree clockwise rotation, so I replaced `"hflip,vflip"` with `transpose=clock`.

Answer (score 1):

**For avconv or ffmpeg Under 14.04 or later**

There have been some changes to the libav documentation since @phoibos quality answer to this question. You can rotate a video 180 degrees avoiding flipping entirely by chaining 2 90 degree commands together (separated by a comma) I accomplished this with the command

avconv -i inputfile -vf transpose=clock,transpose=clock outputfile

for clockwise rotation.

in ffmpeg the syntax is the same.

ffmpeg -i inputfile -vf transpose=clock,transpose=clock outputfile

where inputfile is your supported input video file and outputfile is your desired output file.

For counter clockwise rotation replace clock with cclock

Sources:

https://libav.org/avconv.html#transpose

Testing on Ubuntu 14.04.5 and 16.04 LTS