# Avidemux 2.6.20 installation on Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus failed

Tags: command-line, software-installation, gnome-terminal, 17.04, avidemux

I tried installing Avidemux 2.6.20 on my Ubuntu 17.04 Zesty Zapus by following [the instructions at TipsOnUbuntu](http://tipsonubuntu.com/2017/05/08/install-avidemux-2-6-20-ubuntu-16-04-17-04/), but the Terminal gives me the following response:

```
XXXXs@pop-os:~$ sudo apt update && sudo apt install avidemux2.6-qt
Hit:2 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty InRelease                      
Get:4 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-updates InRelease [89,2 kB]    
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gezakovacs/ppa/ubuntu zesty InRelease           
Get:6 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-security InRelease [89,2 kB]     
Hit:1 http://screenshots.getdeb.net zesty-getdeb InRelease                     
Hit:7 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76-dev/stable/ubuntu zesty InRelease      
Hit:8 https://deb.opera.com/opera-stable stable InRelease                      
Get:3 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb InRelease [9 604 B]          
Get:9 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-backports InRelease [89,2 kB]  
Hit:10 http://ppa.launchpad.net/system76/pop/ubuntu zesty InRelease            
Get:11 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb/apps amd64 Packages [66,5 kB]
Hit:12 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease                          
Get:13 http://screenshots.getdeb.net xenial-getdeb/apps i386 Packages [67,2 kB]
Get:14 http://fi.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu zesty-proposed InRelease [240 kB]   
Fetched 651 kB in 4s (162 kB/s)     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  avidemux2.6-common avidemux2.6-jobs avidemux2.6-plugins-common
  avidemux2.6-plugins-qt lame libaften0 libavidemux2.6 libfaac0
  liblavfile-2.1-0 liblavjpeg-2.1-0 liblavplay-2.1-0 libqt5opengl5
  libquicktime2 mjpegtools mjpegtools-gtk twolame
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  avidemux2.6-common avidemux2.6-jobs avidemux2.6-plugins-common
  avidemux2.6-plugins-qt avidemux2.6-qt lame libaften0 libavidemux2.6 libfaac0
  liblavfile-2.1-0 liblavjpeg-2.1-0 liblavplay-2.1-0 libqt5opengl5
  libquicktime2 mjpegtools mjpegtools-gtk twolame
0 upgraded, 17 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 5 480 kB/7 525 kB of archives.
After this operation, 27,6 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] Y
Err:2 http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu zesty-getdeb/apps amd64 avidemux2.6-plugins-common amd64 1:2.7.0-1~getdeb2~zesty
  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection
Get:1 http://ftp.heanet.ie/pub/www.getdeb.net/getdeb/ubuntu zesty-getdeb/apps amd64 libavidemux2.6 amd64 1:2.7.0-1~getdeb2~zesty [3 064 kB]
Get:3 http://ftp.acc.umu.se/mirror/getdeb.net/ubuntu zesty-getdeb/apps amd64 avidemux2.6-qt amd64 1:2.7.0-1~getdeb2~zesty [1 423 kB]
Fetched 4 487 kB in 1min 6s (67,5 kB/s)                                        
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.getdeb.net/ubuntu/pool/apps/a/avidemux2.6/avidemux2.6-plugins-common_2.7.0-1~getdeb2~zesty_amd64.deb  Error reading from server. Remote end closed connection
E: Unable to fetch some archives, maybe run apt-get update or try with --fix-missing?
XXXXs@pop-os:~$
```

I have no idea why it gives me such error messages. Any ideas how to fix this...? :-(

Comment: It's quite simple, the server is down.

Answer (score 2):

Besides we hear sometimes that Avidemux is dead, it's possible to install it yet. I like it very much, and I successfully installed it in my 17.04 box right now.

1. Download the following file: https://sourceforge.net/projects/avidemux/files/avidemux/2.6.20/avidemux_2.6.20.tar.gz/download
2. `sudo tar -zvxf "into a folder of your preference"` (I suggest /tmp)
3. `sudo apt install libsqlite3-dev qttools5-dev-tools build-essential cmake pkg-config zlib1g-dev zlib1g-dbg yasm qt4-qmake libqt4-dev`
4. `cd /tmp/avidemux_2.6.20`
5. `sudo bash bootStrap.bash`      *** it will delay a bit ****
6. `sudo cp -R install/usr/* /usr/`
7. `gedit ~/Desktop/avidemux.desktop`   (and put this within it):

> ```
> [Desktop Entry]
> Version=2.6.20
> Type=Application
> Terminal=false
> Exec=/usr/bin/avidemux3_qt4
> Name=Avidemux3
> Comment=<comments>
> Icon=icon path here
> ```

Finally,

```
chmod +r ~/Desktop/avidemux.desktop
```

Comment: Jayaguru-Shishya, have you tried install Avidemux after my answer?

Comment: Hi there, and sorry for my most late response! I downloaded the file `avidemux_2.6.20.tar.gz` from the link you gave me to `~/Downloads`.  After that, I tried to run the commands through `Terminal`, which resulted into the following. **First**, `XXXXs@XXXXs:~$ sudo tar -zvxg "/tmp"
tar: Refusing to read archive contents from terminal (missing -f option?)
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now.`

Comment: **Second**, `XXXXs@XXXXs:~/Downloads$ sudo tar -zvxf "/tmp"
tar (child): /tmp: Cannot read: Is a directory
tar (child): At beginning of tape, quitting now
tar (child): Error is not recoverable: exiting now

gzip: stdin: unexpected end of file
tar: Child returned status 2
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now`

What am I doing wrong...? :-(

Comment: You forgot to Target you file. Type `sudo tar -zvxf <file name you downloaded>`

Comment: Thanks for the notice! I've now run the following via Terminal: `XXXXs@XXXXs: /tmp$ sudo tar -zvxf "avidemux_2.6.20.tar.gz"
avidemux_2.6.20/
avidemux_2.6.20/AUTHORS
avidemux_2.6.20/bootStrapHaikuOS.bash
[...]
Setting up libqt4-dev (4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) ...
Setting up libqt4-opengl-dev (4:4.8.7+dfsg-7ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.26-0ubuntu2) ...`

However, running `sudo bash BootStrap.bash` via Terminal, yields me with this:

`XXXXs@XXXXs: /tmp/avidemux_2.6.20$ sudo bash BootStrap.bash
bash: BootStrap.bash: No such file or directory`

Comment: Any ideas...? :-(

Comment: I had to reinstall avidemux, so I followed my own instructions... 
The item 5 was not correct (sorry!!). the correct is `sudo bash bootStrap.bash` (I fixed there yet). It worked very welll!... :-)

Comment: Thanks! I've now installed Avidemux successfully on my system, but one stupid question still remains: where can I find it? I've been trying to find Avidemux through Dash, but with no success ever so far. :O

Comment: Try to `sudo cp ~/desktop/avidemux.desktop /usr/share/applications`, it will be shown in menu, and in dash, too.

Comment: I get an error message: `cp: cannot stat '/home/XXXXs/desktop/avidemux.desktop': No such file or directory.` Hmm, I ran earlier `XXXXs@XXXXs: /tmp/avidemux_2.6.20$ sudo bash bootStrap.bash`, and I could find the only Avidemux related files from the following location: `usr/share/app-install/` What am I ought to copy now, and to which location? And by what command? Thanks a lot, and happy New Year! :-)

Comment: If you followed my tutorial, at point 7 you created a launcher in your desktop. So repeat this command, but type `sudo gedit /use/share/applications/avidemux.desktop` with same contents of that launcher. Happy New Year!

Comment: it works, kind of troublesome, but it seems to be the only option for Ubuntu 17 ....

Comment: @Redbob Thanks, I've never got this far installing `avidemux_2.7.3` (one and half years have already passed, heh). Anyway, I received a `CMake Error` concerning `Qt5Core`. It says that it couldn't find package configuration with any of the following names: `Qt5CoreConfig.cmake`, or `qt5core-config.cmake`. At the end, it says that `Configuring incomplete, errors occurred! ... ** Failed at cmakeZ**` :-O

Comment: @Redbob Yeah, I've followed each one of your steps, including **6)**, **7)**, and the `chmod +r ~/Desktop/avidemux.desktop` one at the end. However, I still can't find Avidemux through `Dash` or anything. Running `sudo cp ~/desktop/avidemux.desktop /usr/share/applications` still returns me with the same `cp: cannot stat '/home/XXXXs/desktop/avidemux.desktop': No such file or directory.`, even though I can see the `avidemux.desktop`file right on my desktop. Moreover, running `sudo gedit /usr/share/applications/avidemux.desktop`, copy-pasting the content given at phase **7)**, and...

Comment: ...saving the file, nothing happens. Well, I get the following four warnings entries in terminal: **1)** `(org.gnome.gedit:17330): Gtk-WARNING **: 19:12:23.703: Calling org.freedesktop.portal.Inhibit.Inhibit failed: GDBus.Error:org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.UnknownMethod: No such interface “org.freedesktop.portal.Inhibit” on object at path /org/freedesktop/portal/desktop,` **2)** `** (org.gnome.gedit:17330): WARNING **: 19:12:26.203: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-spell-language not supported`, **3)** `** (org.gnome.gedit:17330): WARNING **: 19:12:26.205: Set` ...

Comment: ... `document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-encoding not supported`, and **4)** `* (org.gnome.gedit:17330): WARNING **: 19:12:29.353: Set document metadata failed: Setting attribute metadata::gedit-position not supported`. I do have replaced the second line of `avidemux.desktop`, that is `Version=2.6.20`, with the actual version, `Version=2.7.30`. I don't know what to do next. I feel rather stupid and frustrated not even knowing how to RUN a program installed on my system. Ufff, but I still wouldn't want to give up with Linux ... although I such an ever-newbie I am :-P

Answer (score 1):

The server at http://archive.getdeb.net is getting a `526 error, invalid SSL certificate`. Until they resolve this problem at the server end, you won't be able to get this file.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! That's a pity, I guess there's nothing much to do than wait. Meanwhile, I might have a look at some other alternatives listed in [another thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83711/how-can-i-rotate-a-video). Thanks still!