# How to convert an mp4 video by 180 degrees using ffmpeg or mencoder

Tags: 16.04, video, ffmpeg, mp4, mencoder

After reading about [how to convert a video by 90 degrees](https://askubuntu.com/questions/83711/how-can-i-rotate-a-video%20I%20failed%20to%20permanently%20convert%20a%20video%20by%20180%20degrees.)

I tried these commands:

```
mencoder old.mp4 -oac lavc -ovc x264 vcodec=mpeg4 -vf flip,mirror -o new.mp4

mencoder old.mp4 -oac lavc -ovc x264 vcodec=mpeg4 -vf rotate=2 -o new.mp4

ffmpeg -i old.mp4 -vf "hflip" -strict -2 new.mp4
```

but the converted video is still upside down.

Running the video with

```
mplayer -vf flip,mirror  old.mp4
```

renders it as desired. But anyway, I'd like to *convert* it.

I'm using 
`ffmpeg version 2.8.15-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` and 
`MEncoder 1.2.1 (Debian), built with gcc-5.3.1`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Videos from phones often have metadata that tell the player to rotate upon playback (not all players respect this). When re-encoding, `ffmpeg` will automatically rotate the video according to the rotate metadata, so you don't have to do anything special:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

However, if the rotate metadata is wrong you can simply remove or change it without needing to re-encode:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -c copy -metadata:s:v rotate="" output.mp4
```

Alternatively, you could change it such as `-metadata:s:v rotate="180"`.

Comment: The last one `rotate="180"` worked for me. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for explaining specifics of videos from phones!

Answer (score 0):

I found the following command line code worked with Ubuntu 20.04LTS using ffmpeg:

```
ffmpeg -i filename.mp4 \
-c copy -metadata:s:v:0 rotate=0 \
output.mp4
```

It only changes the metadata with no loss in quality.